# Database connection error in Toad/SQL when trying to use the procedure in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I get this error when I try to set the database location as the custom procedure. What am I missing to get rid of this error?

[image: Database Error]

Comment: code please and how you design you crystal report ?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Causes**

Your report uses functions calls or store procedure, your login is not allowed to run function and stored procedures
Your login does not have select permission for the database/table
Other permission related **problem
Solution**

By allowing read or execute permission will fix the problem. If it is just one one function call /store procedure that is causing the problem, the following command will be helpful

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.my_function TO [user/role]
```

Comment: Can I set it to public instead of a specific user? Or does it have to be a specific user at the end of the GRANT code?

Comment: You Can set to Public Try  And Mark !